# JQuery and Bootstrap: Bad Nav Dropdown Bug

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, nav

Im having an issue wih the dropdowns using jquery and bootstrap. It seemed to be a common thing on previous releases and I cannot understand why I am getting the errors currently. The html is below:

```
<html>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
        ...Collapsible definition for mobile...
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-medium" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 1</a>
                <ul class="col-sm-3">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Header 1</li>
                    <li><a href="Page1.aspx">Page1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript/>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript/>
</html>
```

Now the issue im getting relates to the first click for the dropdown and the href="#". The jquery is trying to parse it as a link or page apparently? The full error is below:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax VM jquery-3.3.1.js:1541 error, unrecognized
>   expression: # 
> at Function.Sizzle.error (VM29 jquery-3.1.1.js:
>   1541) 
> at Function.Sizzle.tokenize (VM29 jquery-3.1.1.js: 2193)
>   
> at Function.Sizzle.select (VM29 jquery-3.1.1.js: 2620) 
> at
>   Function.Sizzle [as find] (VM29 jquery-3.1.1.js: 845) 
> at
>   JQuery.fn.init.find (VM29 jquery-3.1.1.js: 2873) 
> at new
>   JQuery.fn.init (VM29 jquery-3.1.1.js: 2983) 
> at JQuery (VM29
>   jquery-3.1.1.js: 139) 
> at getParent (VM30 bootstrap.js: 298)
>   
> ...html anchor data

Note that I have also tried using Jquery 2.2.4...the menu doesnt show and i dont get errors. I have gotten it to work locally by installing jquery 3.3.1, and importing jquery 2.2.4 on that page instead of the 3.3.1 version...it worked locally but does not work when published.

EDIT
Adding popper.js from the umd folder between the two script imports and I still get the same error

EDIT 2
This is the custom CSS I am using.
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/large-dropdown-menu
This works locally, though in a weird way. Nuget package JQuery 2.2.4 installed and left in the .net bundle as such, but using the 3.1.1 version in the script section on the page and it works. If i update to the 3.3.1 version, I get that error. Bootstrap version 3.0.0 and 4.1.1 mixed and tried different combos, but all either just flat out didnt work or got the error message.

EDIT3 Live example
The nav section and css is a direct copy from the said working snippet in the answers section. **The installed scripts via nuget manager match the versions**
(the redirects for http on the page are for the placeholders.) CLicking on the dropdown yields nothing...

EDIT 4
Thank you to fnostro (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1971438) for talking and debugging...script manager was loading over the load in the  tag and also different versions of each were loaded.

Nuget Packages
Jquery 3.3.1
Bootstrap 4.1.1

Comment: It seems you missed to link `popper.js`

Comment: I've tried adding that in between the jquery and bootstrap but that does not fix it either...

Comment: Your navbar doesn't seem to be marked up properly for BS 4.1.1 dropdown.  see [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dropdown is not styled or marked up as expected for a 4.1.1 dropdown.  Plus you are missing a closing quote on your class and a closing anchor end tag.

```
  <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-medium" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu col-sm-3">
      <span class="dropdown-header">Header 1</span>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="Page1.aspx">Page1</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-medium" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 1</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu col-sm-3">
          <span class="dropdown-header">Header 1</span>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="Page1.aspx">Page1</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

## Snippet Large DropDown using jquery 2.1.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.7

### Works as expected

```css
.dropdown-large {
  position: static !important;
}

.dropdown-menu-large {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: normal;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li ul>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large>li ul>li>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:focus {
  color: #999999;
}

.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-menu-large {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large>li {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large>li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
    padding: 3px 15px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Large Dropdown Menu</a>
  </div>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row">
          <li class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Glyphicons</li>
              <li><a href="#">Available glyphs</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#">How to use</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdowns</li>
              <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Aligninment options</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Headers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Disabled menu items</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Button groups</li>
              <li><a href="#">Basic example</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Button toolbar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sizing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Nesting</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Vertical variation</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Button dropdowns</li>
              <li><a href="#">Single button dropdowns</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Input groups</li>
              <li><a href="#">Basic example</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sizing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Checkboxes and radio addons</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Navs</li>
              <li><a href="#">Tabs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pills</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Justified</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Navbar</li>
              <li><a href="#">Default navbar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Non-nav links</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Component alignment</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fixed to top</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fixed to bottom</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Static top</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Inverted navbar</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
</nav>
```

## Snippet Large DropDown using jquery 3.1.1 and Bootstrap 4.1.1

### Seems to be incompatible

```css
.dropdown-large {
  position: static !important;
}

.dropdown-menu-large {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li>ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: normal;
}

.dropdown-menu-large>li ul>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large>li ul>li>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:focus {
  color: #999999;
}

.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-menu-large {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large>li {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large>li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
    padding: 3px 15px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Large Dropdown Menu</a>
  </div>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row">
          <li class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Glyphicons</li>
              <li><a href="#">Available glyphs</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#">How to use</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdowns</li>
              <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Aligninment options</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Headers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Disabled menu items</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Button groups</li>
              <li><a href="#">Basic example</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Button toolbar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sizing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Nesting</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Vertical variation</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Button dropdowns</li>
              <li><a href="#">Single button dropdowns</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Input groups</li>
              <li><a href="#">Basic example</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sizing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Checkboxes and radio addons</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Navs</li>
              <li><a href="#">Tabs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pills</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Justified</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Navbar</li>
              <li><a href="#">Default navbar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Non-nav links</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Component alignment</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fixed to top</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fixed to bottom</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Static top</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Inverted navbar</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: I am using a snippet meant for bootstrap snippet. See EDIT2

Comment: the snippet is meant to work under Bootstrap 3.0.0 as per snippet author, however it works under 3.3.7, but not 4.1.1.  You would need to reconfigure all the markup to comply with 4.1.1 dropdowns to get it to work, or use 3.3.7 in your environment.

Comment: I've tried using BS 3.0.0 and it still fails though

Comment: if your using the markup in your post it's still missing the closing `</a>` in your example

Comment: Other than that, clearly it works if you run the 3.3.7 snippet above. Switch view as "full screen"

Comment: Sorry about the missing tags, typing from phone and remoting into computer via tv so I had to retype everything....Ive tried the above..no error but it just doesnt load anything...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172528/discussion-between-matthew-wherry-and-fnostro).